# Data Driven OpenSource Thermometer for website

Tags: asp.net, open-source, controls, gauge

I am looking for an open source Thermometer that i can connect to a JSON or XML datasource and display this on my website.

The site is an asp.net site so javascript controls are not a problem.

My Googling didn't reveal very much at all.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: are you looking for a graphic or the actual hardware?

Comment: I am looking for a visual control that i can add to a page and use it to display data from a DB in a graphical format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of the exact solution. But you can play with jQuery progress bar as mentioned here
[jQuery sponsorship thermometer](http://www.webdesignerforum.co.uk/topic/42857-jquery-sponsorship-thermometer/)
and
[Progress Bars & Controls](http://t.wits.sg/misc/jQueryProgressBar/demo.php)

You can also look at the [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) site where they implement their progress bar just using div elements in the following way:

```
   <div title="39% (Commitment: 18%)" class="status-bar">
        <div class="grey-bar"></div>
        <div style="width: 39.5%;" class="color-bar"></div>
        <div class="ticks-left">define</div>
        <div class="ticks-middle">commit</div>
        <div class="ticks-right">beta</div>
    </div>
```